# Im learning bash, confused with command line arguments

Tags: linux, bash

I need to create a script that allows a command line argument to be passed and checked to see if it exists as a directory within the directory im running the script in. If it does list the contents and if it doesnt print a error message.
So at the command line I should type ./check.sh test(existing directory)
and the script should run. Now I don't understand how to use test which should be $1. In the script I want to  take $1 and check it against existing directories. however if i do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=$1
cd DIR
ls
```

it doesn't work because DIR doesn't take on the argument(in this case test)
I know I need to use an if-else block but I dont understand how to get the information I need to begin with. Please someone help me figure this out.

Comment: You forgot the `$` Try `cd $DIR`

Comment: You need to use $DIR and you can use `test(1)` to actually test whether the directory is there. As it stands, if DIR doesn't exist, your `ls` will run in the current directory. You can also shorten that to `cd $DIR && ls`.

Comment: Actually you don't have to cd to $DIR. You can simply do `ls $DIR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted something like

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$1"
#test if $DIR is a directory.
if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
    cd "$DIR"
    ls
fi
```

Or, you could have used `$1` throughout (it's shorter than $DIR, and I would prefer to use `env` to search for `bash` - it isn't always `/bin/bash`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
    cd "$1"
    ls
fi
```

Comment: To elaborate a bit on @ElliottFrisch's answer. Take a look at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html regarding file test operators in bash. as well as http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_07.html to gain an understanding of conditional logic in bash

Comment: Thank you that helped alot!

Comment: @anon_guy if `Elliot Frisch` provided you with the answer you were looking for then perhaps you should mark his answer as your accepted answer to your question